# Handling two layouts in single dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I’ve got about 8 categories of detail pages, half of which are detail pages, the other half are editorial pages. The data for these 2 page types is entirely different, and **nesting one route in a subfolder is not an option**.

```
pages/[detailPageCategory]/[slug].js
pages/[editorialPageCategory]/[slug].js
```

Ideally I’d create separate page components for both to separate concerns but Nextjs cannot handle two dynamic routes one the same level.

```
pages/[pageType]/[slug].js
```

Would the best idea be to handle both routes in a single dynamic route? This feels unclean, since both pages are bundled together, and I'll need to pass a prop to the page `pageType={layout1|layout2}` and handle both cases within the page component, not separating concerns.

```js
const DynamicRoutePage = ({ pageType, data }) => {
  if (pageType === "detail") {
    return (
      <DetailPage {...data} />
    )
  }
  if (pageType === "editorial") {
    return (
      <EditorialPage {...data} />
    )
  }
  return null
}
```

Are there best practices of how to approach this? Perhaps Next’s ‘getLayout’ function?

Answer (score 3):

> You can create containers Folder, and in that you can have template
> for each categories pages, in this way you can separate out different
> pages UI's.

In the actual pages, you can [dynamic import][1] that based on the pageType.

*So that the pages Template will be spitted into different chunks, and it will not be loaded all at once.*

```
const DetailPage = dynamic(() => import('../containers/DetailPage'))
const EditorialPage = dynamic(() => import('../containers/EditorialPage'))

const DynamicRoutePage = ({ pageType, data }) => {
  if (pageType === "detail") {
    return (
      <DetailPage {...data} />
    )
  }
  if (pageType === "editorial") {
    return (
      <EditorialPage {...data} />
    )
  }
  return null
}
```

Comment: True, but i still face the issue of conditional rendering in a single page component, which i was hoping i could circumvent. The project is large and complex… being explicit about what page renders which data is very important.

Comment: There's no alternative for this, this is how nextjs works. That's why they have removed most of the routing features and given powe to pages structure only